# Accessing google calendar events by passing token

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get google calendar events by passing token.I am using angularjs and spring mvc.At first i am doing user signup by integrating google signin.After signin i am getting token_id.I am saving this token_id.Now for accessing calendar i have enabled calendar api in google developer console.And I have created project and obtained clientId.

Here is how i am getting token_id

html

```
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="client_id"> <!--client id obtained from creating project in google developer console -->
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" > </div>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
    </script>
```

controller.js

```
    function onSignIn(googleUser)
    {
      console.log(googleUser.getAuthResponse());
      $scope.profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      $scope.authToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
      console.log('Name: ' + $scope.profile.getName());
      console.log('Token: ' + $scope.authToken);
      $scope.saveAuthToken();/*here i am calling another method to save token*/
    }
```

In the googleUser object i am getting two tokens one is access_token and other is id_token.I am using id_token.

Here i am sending token to backened for saving

```
    $scope.saveAuthToken = function(){
        var googleAccessToken = $scope.authToken;
        AccountSettingService.saveAuthToken(googleAccessToken).then(function(response){
            if(response!=null){
                alert('saved');
        }
        });
        }
```

The token i am getting after signin is in this format for example

```
    eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjNlMTg3MTc3Zj... still more to go with characters.
```

At the backened i am calling google api with the saved token to access calendar events

GoogleController.java

```
    @Override
    public List<Event> getEventsFromGoogleCalendar(String googleToken) 
    throws IOException 
    {
      System.out.println(""+googleToken);
      GoogleCredential credential = new 
      GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(googleToken);
      Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
      JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
      .setApplicationName("applicationName")
      .build();
      String pageToken = null;
      Events events = 
      service.events().list("primary").setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
      List<Event> items = events.getItems();
      System.out.println(""+items);
      return items ;
}
```

I am getting this error

```
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401
    Unauthorized
    {
      "code" : 401,
      "errors" : [ {
      "domain" : "global",
      "location" : "Authorization",
      "locationType" : "header",
      "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
      "reason" : "authError"
     } ],
      "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
    }
```

I am able to signin and get the token.But not able to retrieve calendar events.
Can anyone tell where i am doing wrong.I know the token is only valid for one hour but within one hour if i try also its not working.Am i sending correct token to the google?or is there any other token i have to send?or am i missing something in the whole process?

Comment: you need to send the access token not the id token i beleave

Comment: Can you tell how to get access token.What is the get method to get access token.I found get method only for token_id

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: I went through but they mentioned to send id_token to backened